# Php is not working but iframe is working fine

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I have few sets of code to display right side of my webpage. I am using this place to show some user information and some short of ads. For ads I am using that code in my database. Now the problem is that I want to display one external php file which is located in the same directory where I am trying to include or require this php file.

But I dont know why this is not working. I tried with `iframe` that works fine but I want to use php `include` but it is not working .please tell where I am doing mistake. Here is my code:

```
if (is_array($data['blocks'])) {
        $output .= '<div id="appside">';
        foreach($data['blocks'] as $block) {
            if (is_array($block)) {
                $output .= '
                <div class="block">';
                if ($block['title']) {
                    $output .= '<div class="block_title">'.$block['title'].'</div>';
                }
                $output .= '<div class="block_content">
                '.$block['content'].
                '</div>
                </div>
                ';
            }
        }
        $output .= get_gvar('theme_block_sidebar').

        '<div><?php include("/home/xxxxxxx/public_html/xxxxxxxa.php"); ?></div>


        </div>

                ';// end of app_sidebar
```

I tried with all short of alternatives but its printing raw php code. its not getting executed. I tried to put `<?php   include(\'/home/xxxxxxx/public_html/xxxxxxxa.php\'); ?>`
and all other sort of alternatives but its printing raw php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the file you wish to include is in the same directory as this file, then you should include the filename only

```
<?php include('filename.php'); ?>
```

if it is in a higher level or in a directory or a sub-directory in a higher level, then you should move up to this level then down to the file.

```
<?php include('../../path/to/file.php'); ?>
```

where `../../` is going up 2 levels, you can set it to as many levels you want to go up.

Comment: i tried with all alternatives as suggested by you like only file.php and .../ also but its not working

Comment: can you post the contents of the file that is not working not only the function and a snapshot of the directory tree of your server (with folders expanded)?? you can hide your username/FTP details and any sensitive data

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> '<div><?php include("/home/xxxxxxx/public_html/xxxxxxxa.php"); ?></div>
> ```

PHP won't execute inside a string (which is all the above is).

You can't really concatenate an include statement (unless the included file returns something via `return`). Given I can't tell if your code snippet is inside a function or how it's executed, my best solution is to use output buffering.

```
$output .= get_gvar('theme_block_sidebar') . '<div>';

ob_start();
include "/home/xxxxxxx/public_html/xxxxxxxa.php";
$output .= ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();

$output .= '</div>'
```

Comment: working but all function of page is not working.page contains several img,in 1st load i am loading 10 img and as the user goes down it will load 5 img.script is working fine in iframe but here with your method only 1st set of 10 img are loaded . i want that additional set of 5 images to get loaded as the user scroll and goes down . do you have any idea whats happening. i guess with ob_start thar page is treated as seperate page .????? as i have not included javascript and css is that particular page as these js and css file is already there in main page where i am including this file.php

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the output from an external php file in a variable, you can get it using the [PHP buffering functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php):

```
ob_start();
include("/home/xxxxxxx/public_html/xxxxxxxa.php");
$output_from_php_file = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

Then you can append `$output_from_php_file` to your `$output` variable wherever you want.

Comment: working but all function of page is not working.page contains several img,in 1st load i am loading 10 img and as the user goes down it will load 5 img.script is working fine in iframe but here with your method only 1st set of 10 img are loaded . i want that additional set of 5 images to get loaded as the user scroll and goes down . do you have any idea whats happening. i guess with ob_start thar page is treated as seperate page .????? as i have not included javascript and css is that particular page as these js and css file is already there in main page where i am including this file.php